# Multiple variables in Photoshop

Tags: variables, dataset, photoshop

Is it possible to make multiple variables in Photoshop somehow? What I mean is that I'm responsible for newsletters in company I work for. We send newsletters with many products showed and their prices added. We work in Google Sheets where I copy data from to the PSD file, +/- 25 products for every single newsletter, 16 times as it is prepared for 16 different markets. It looks like this:

Product1 - OldPrice NewPrice
Product2 - OldPrice NewPrice
Product3 - OldPrice NewPrice

etc.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to automate the process.

Comment: From what I gather, you might be better off using Photoshop scripting (JavaScript, Visual basic or Applescript) to do what you want. You can certainly read data from a .CSV and get theat to switch layers on/off.

Comment: Have you tried to do any research? There's a feature called Variables in Photoshop exactly for that